# Integrating a cross product.

Tags: integration, cross-product

I am given that $\mathbf{k} . m \mathbf{q} \wedge \mathbf{\ddot{q}} = 0$ and my book says that integrating this wrt time gives $\mathbf{k}.m \mathbf{q} \wedge \mathbf{\dot{q}} = $constant. I don't understand why this is. I've tried finding an explanation of integrating cross product but haven't really been able to find anything useful, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110462/how-do-you-integrate-cross-products) seems similar but I still can't figure out how it works.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you integrate Cross Products?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110462/how-do-you-integrate-cross-products)

Comment: @HansLundmark: The OP does point out that they are aware of this other questions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume that your $\lor$ is the cross product, which I usually write as $\times$.

If you have two vector functions $\vec{f}(t)$ and $\vec{g}(t)$ (with values in $\mathbb{R}^3$) , then you can form the cross product: $\vec{f}(t)\times \vec{g}(t)$. This is again a vector function. To take the derivative, the [rule is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Differentiation) that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{f}(t)\times \vec{g}(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\vec{f}(t)\times \vec{g}(t) + \vec{f}(t)\times \frac{d}{dt} \vec{g}(t).
$$
In other words it works just like the product rule for real valued functions.

Now, in your case you want to take the integral of a cross product. You can do this by verifying that the derivative of $\mathbf{k}.m \mathbf{q} \wedge \mathbf{\dot{q}}$ indeed is $\mathbf{k} . m \mathbf{q} \wedge \mathbf{\ddot{q}} = 0$.

First note that the $\bf{k}$ doesn't matter because it is a constant ([see this](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Dot_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions)). Likewise with the $m$. Now [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110474/26188) tells you exactly how you can do this.