# Evaluating the double integral of a cross product (to prove Gaussian Curvature)

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curvature

My end goal is to show why Gauss's original equation for curvature is equivalent to the modern definition. Stated differently, explain why $$K= \lim_{A\to p}\frac{Area(n(u))}{Area(U)}=\frac{eg-f^2}{EG-F^2}$$ where e,f, and g are the coefficients of the second fundamental form and E,F,G are the coefficients of the first fundamental form.  With the help of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198377/proof-that-the-gaussian-curvature-is-a-ratio-of-areas) and my class notes, I've been able to work out a solution up to the point where the integral of a cross product comes into play. In other words, I'm not sure how the integral is evaluated to get $$\int \int_{V_{\epsilon}}||X_u \times X_v|| du dv = ||X_u(u_{\epsilon},v_{\epsilon}) \times X_v(u_{\epsilon},v_{\epsilon})||$$ and $$\int \int_{V_{\epsilon}}||N_u \times N_v|| du dv = |K(u^{'}_{\epsilon},v^{'}_{\epsilon})|||X_u(u^{'}_{\epsilon},v^{'}_{\epsilon}) \times X_v(u^{'}_{\epsilon},v^{'}_{\epsilon})||$$

I looked at both [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084564/integrating-a-cross-product) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110462/how-do-you-integrate-cross-products/110474#110474) in hopes of figuring it out on my own. Based on those I was hoping the derivative of $||X\times X_v||$ would be the result of the first integral, but the derivative gives $||X_u\times X_v||+||X\times X_{uv}||$ and I cannot assume that $X_{uv}$ is zero.

Comment: Your post is a bit hard to follow. So you're trying to see what the limit of the ratio of the area of the Gauss image to the area of a little piece of surface is the determinant of the shape operator. The first integral is approximately $\det(I)\text{area}(V_\epsilon)$ and the second integral is approximately $\det(II)\text{area}(V_\epsilon)$. The calculation you suggest is just flawed and wouldn't go anywhere anyhow. To see what's going on, you might assume that the $u$- and $v$-curves are lines of curvature, as this simplifies things; then go back and do the general case.

Comment: Further comment: The posts you've linked to about integrating cross products are truly not helpful. You have *magnitudes* of cross products in both your integrals. These show up as "fudge factors" when you see how mappings distort area.